# Unsupported pseudo CSS selector: :root while converting HTML to PDF

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, itext7, html2pdf

I got an error while converting HTML to pdf using **itextpdf-html2pdf**. I used Bootstrap 3 in HTML. and the error is :

```
2019-04-26 12:13:22.240 ERROR 19740 --- [nio-8100-exec-3] c.i.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser  : Error while parsing css selector: svg:not(:root)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported pseudo css selector: :root
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.appendPseudoSelector(CssSelectorParser.java:207) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.parseSelectorItems(CssSelectorParser.java:117) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.CssSelector.<init>(CssSelector.java:74) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.item.CssPseudoClassSelectorItem.create(CssPseudoClassSelectorItem.java:107) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.item.CssPseudoClassSelectorItem.create(CssPseudoClassSelectorItem.java:95) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.appendPseudoSelector(CssSelectorParser.java:205) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.parseSelectorItems(CssSelectorParser.java:117) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.CssSelector.<init>(CssSelector.java:74) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser.parseRuleSet(CssRuleSetParser.java:132) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.processProperties(CssParserStateController.java:390) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.storeCurrentProperties(CssParserStateController.java:315) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.PropertiesState.process(PropertiesState.java:71) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.process(CssParserStateController.java:179) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssStyleSheetParser.parse(CssStyleSheetParser.java:125) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.resolve.DefaultCssResolver.collectCssDeclarations(DefaultCssResolver.java:316) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.resolve.DefaultCssResolver.<init>(DefaultCssResolver.java:137) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:264) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:78) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:371) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:149) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:136) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:111) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:98) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.service.HtmlToPdfService.generatePdf(HtmlToPdfService.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.service.AboutService.downloadResume(AboutService.java:2215) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController.downloadResume(AboutController.java:650) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$79022650.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8372e06c.downloadResume(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor331.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

2019-04-26 12:13:22.283 ERROR 19740 --- [nio-8100-exec-3] c.i.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser  : Error while parsing css selector: .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported pseudo css selector: :nth-of-type(odd)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.appendPseudoSelector(CssSelectorParser.java:207) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.parseSelectorItems(CssSelectorParser.java:117) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.CssSelector.<init>(CssSelector.java:74) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser.parseRuleSet(CssRuleSetParser.java:132) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.processProperties(CssParserStateController.java:390) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.storeCurrentProperties(CssParserStateController.java:315) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.PropertiesState.process(PropertiesState.java:71) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.process(CssParserStateController.java:179) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssStyleSheetParser.parse(CssStyleSheetParser.java:125) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.resolve.DefaultCssResolver.collectCssDeclarations(DefaultCssResolver.java:316) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.resolve.DefaultCssResolver.<init>(DefaultCssResolver.java:137) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:264) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:78) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:371) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:149) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:136) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:111) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:98) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.service.HtmlToPdfService.generatePdf(HtmlToPdfService.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.service.AboutService.downloadResume(AboutService.java:2215) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController.downloadResume(AboutController.java:650) [classes/:na]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$79022650.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.cynnox.socialmedia.controller.AboutController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8372e06c.downloadResume(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor331.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

2019-04-26 12:13:22.289 ERROR 19740 --- [nio-8100-exec-3] c.i.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser  : Error while parsing css selector: .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported pseudo css selector: :-ms-input-placeholder
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.appendPseudoSelector(CssSelectorParser.java:207) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssSelectorParser.parseSelectorItems(CssSelectorParser.java:117) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.selector.CssSelector.<init>(CssSelector.java:74) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser.parseRuleSet(CssRuleSetParser.java:132) ~[html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.processProperties(CssParserStateController.java:390) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.storeCurrentProperties(CssParserStateController.java:315) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.PropertiesState.process(PropertiesState.java:71) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.parse.syntax.CssParserStateController.process(CssParserStateController.java:179) [html2pdf-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at
```

used dependecies are:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
<version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and my html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Resume</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.resume-ul {
    margin: 0 -23px 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <!-- photoView -->
                    <img th:src="@{${resumeRes.heading.photo.thumbnail}}" alt="people"
                        gravity="faces" height="150" width="150" scale="fill" />

                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <h4>
                        <b>[(${resumeRes.heading.firstName})][(${resumeRes.heading.lastName})]</b>
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                        [(${resumeRes.heading.streetAddress})]
                        [(${resumeRes.heading.town})] [(${resumeRes.heading.postCode})] <br>
                        [(${resumeRes.heading.mail})] [(${resumeRes.heading.phone})]
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can convert this HTML to pdf no problem in output. but the problem is there is an error log. How can I fix this? Why does html2pdf fail to parse bootstrap?

Comment: If the output looks good then you can just ignore this error. This is a logger message which indicates that `:root` selector is unsupported. It might not be used in your HTML after all

Comment: Thankyou Alexey Subach